# Como utilizar un array de un objeto

Tags: java, array, poo

Tengo una clase `Alumnos` donde declaro un `Array` de tres elementos:

```
public class Alumnos extends Persona 
{
   private int numeroExpediente;
   private int nota[];

   public Alumnos()
   {
       numeroExpediente=0;
       int nota[] = new int[3];
   }

   public Alumnos(String nombre,String direccion,String fecha,String sexo, int numeroExpediente, int nota[])
   {
       super(nombre,direccion,fecha,sexo);
       this.numeroExpediente=numeroExpediente;
       this.nota[3]=nota[3];
   }

   public int getNumeroExpediente() {
       return numeroExpediente;
   }

   public void setNumeroExpediente(int numeroExpediente) {
       this.numeroExpediente = numeroExpediente;
   }

   public int[] getNota() {
       return nota;
   }

   public void setNota(int[] nota) {
       this.nota = nota;
   }    
}
```

Quiero utilizarlo en la clase `main` con el objeto `Alumnos`, pero no se como ponerlo para introducir tres notas:

```
public class Principal 
{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner tecla = new Scanner(System.in);
       Alumnos objAlumnos = new Alumnos();
       Empleados objEmpleados = new Empleados();
       int opcion;

       System.out.println("Datos personales\n");

       System.out.println("\t 1---> Alumnos");
       System.out.println("\t 2---> Empleados");
       System.out.print("\nElija una opcion: ");
       opcion=tecla.nextInt();

       if(opcion==1)
       {
           System.out.println(tecla.nextLine());
           System.out.print("Nombre del alumno: ");
           objAlumnos.setNombre(tecla.nextLine());
           System.out.print("Direccion: ");
           objAlumnos.setDireccion(tecla.nextLine());
           System.out.print("Fecha de nacimiento: ");
           objAlumnos.setFecha(tecla.nextLine());
           System.out.print("Sexo del alumno: ");
           objAlumnos.setSexo(tecla.nextLine());
           System.out.print("Numero de Expediente: ");
           objAlumnos.setNumeroExpediente(tecla.nextInt());
           for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
           {
               System.out.print("Nota 1: ");
               objAlumnos.setNota(tecla.nextInt());//Aqui me da fallo
           }            
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: Me da este error: The method setNota(int[]) in the type Alumnos is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Claro, como parámetro de entrada del método setNota() has definido que sea un array de enteros. El método setNota de la clase Alumnos tiene que tener como parámetro de entrada un entero, quedaría así: public void setNota(int nota)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema del error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` esta en el constructor que no recibe parametros de tu clase `Alumnos`, ya que en el no estas inicializando la variable `nota`, si no que estas creando otra variable. Para solucionar este error tienes que realizar la siguiente correccion:

```
public class Alumnos extends Persona 
{
   private int numeroExpediente;
   private int nota[];

   public Alumnos()
   {
       numeroExpediente=0;
       nota = new int[3]; // Inicializas la variable notas
   }

   public Alumnos(String nombre,String direccion,String fecha,String sexo, int numeroExpediente, int nota[])
   {
       super(nombre,direccion,fecha,sexo);
       this.numeroExpediente=numeroExpediente;
       this.nota = nota;
   }

   public int getNumeroExpediente() {
       return numeroExpediente;
   }

   public void setNumeroExpediente(int numeroExpediente) {
       this.numeroExpediente = numeroExpediente;
   }

   public int[] getNota() {
       return nota;
   }

   public void setNota(int[] nota) {
       this.nota = nota;
   }    
}
```

Con eso ya no te debe de dar error.

Answer (score 4):

Por lo general los métodos `set` de una Colección o Array esperan como argumento un Array del tipo indicado, por lo que tu método `setNota(int [] nota)` espera que le pases como argumento un Array de `int` lo cual deberías usarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner tecla = new Scanner(System.in);
   Alumnos objAlumnos = new Alumnos();
   Empleados objEmpleados = new Empleados();
   int opcion;

   System.out.println("Datos personales\n");

   System.out.println("\t 1---> Alumnos");
   System.out.println("\t 2---> Empleados");
   System.out.print("\nElija una opcion: ");
   opcion=tecla.nextInt();

   if(opcion==1)
   {
       System.out.println(tecla.nextLine());
       System.out.print("Nombre del alumno: ");
       objAlumnos.setNombre(tecla.nextLine());
       System.out.print("Direccion: ");
       objAlumnos.setDireccion(tecla.nextLine());
       System.out.print("Fecha de nacimiento: ");
       objAlumnos.setFecha(tecla.nextLine());
       System.out.print("Sexo del alumno: ");
       objAlumnos.setSexo(tecla.nextLine());
       System.out.print("Numero de Expediente: ");
       objAlumnos.setNumeroExpediente(tecla.nextInt());
       int[] notas = new int[3];
       for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       {
           System.out.print("Nota " + (i+1) + ": ");
           notas[i]=tecla.nextInt();
       }     
       objAlumnos.setNota(notas);
   }
}
```

De todas formas deberías cambiar el nombre de la variable a `notas` ya que representa un conjunto de elementos tipo `int` y no un solo elemento.

Comment: Me sale este error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at Datos_Personales.Principal.main(Principal.java:38)

Comment: tengo en la clase Alumnos el metodo toString() asi puesto :  public String toString() {
  return "Nombre = " + nombre + "\nDireccion = " + direccion + "\nFecha de nacimiento = " + fecha + 
    "\nSexo = " + sexo + "\nNumeroExpediente = " + numeroExpediente + "\nNota 1 = " + nota[0] + 
    "\nNota 2 = " + nota[1] + "\nNota 3 = " +nota[2];
 }

Comment: trata modificando tu constructor sin argumentos por esto 
public Alumnos()
   {
       this.numeroExpediente=0;
       this.nota = new int[3];
   }
ya que no inicializas el array

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que intentas acceder a una posición del array de notas que no existe.

Las arrays en Java y muchos otros lenguajes de programación comienzan en 0 hasta n-1.

#### En las propiedades

> private int nota[] = new int[3] en vez de private int nota[]

#### En el cuerpo de tu constructor

> this.nota[2] = nota[2] en vez de this.nota[3] = nota[3]

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error que cosa mas rara

Comment: No tienes definido el array en ningún constructor ni en las propiedades de la clase y tu método setNota espera un array de enteros en vez de un valor como le estás pasando.

Comment: Cómo defino el array amigo?

Comment: Ahora mismo lo tienes declarado es decir apunta a null, puedes definirlo en el constructor o bien en línea a la hora de declarar la propiedad.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el constructor. Aquí:

```
public Alumnos()
{
    numeroExpediente=0;
    //aquí, nota es una variable local, no tu atributo
    int nota[] = new int[3];
}

public Alumnos(String nombre,String direccion,String fecha,String sexo, int numeroExpediente, int nota[])
{
    super(nombre,direccion,fecha,sexo);
    this.numeroExpediente=numeroExpediente;
    //aquí estás obteniendo el 4to elemento del parámetro nota
    //y asignándolo al atributo nota que no ha sido inicializado
    this.nota[3]=nota[3];
}
```

O bien inicializas el arreglo al declararlo como atributo o lo inicializas en cada constructor de acuerdo a lo que se necesite.

Ejemplo:

```
public Alumnos()
{
    numeroExpediente=0;
    //se inicializa el arreglo con 3 elementos como máximo
    //los índices varían entre el 0, 1 y 2
    this.nota = new int[3];
}

public Alumnos(String nombre,String direccion,String fecha,String sexo, int numeroExpediente, int nota[])
{
    super(nombre,direccion,fecha,sexo);
    this.numeroExpediente=numeroExpediente;
    //inicializar el atributo nota como una copia del parámetro nota
    //copiar los elementos del parámetro nota al atributo nota
    this.nota = new int[nota.length];
    for (int i = 0; i <= nota.length; nota++) {
        this.nota[i] = nota[i];
    }
}
```